# How to display a field twice in a view mode?

Tags: 8, entities

I'd like to display a field_address in a view mode twice, once as the displayed address and once as a google maps directions link.  I suppose I could create one custom field formatter that outputs both components, but it seems excessive to create a formatter to display basically what should be two formatters.

Is there a way, say in hook_entity_view to display a field twice with two formatters?  Basically say $build['field_address_direction'] = $build['field_address'] and then change the formatter?

Comment: Have you tried/thought of using [Views](//drupal.org/project/views)?

Comment: It's funny, in this case, I'm already using views, but rendering the node with a view mode.  This is for my main search, and not all content types or entities have field_address, although, I like being able to have templates for each entity type.  I guess you can do that with views as well, different templates for each content type?  At this point, I don't think I would want to do it that way, as I'm 99% there, and I could just do some custom code in hook_entity_view to format the address.  I'm just thinking in terms of future development, it would be nice to use a formatter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to display a field twice in `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view()`, you can get the field object from the first field and clone the field with a different field formatter and custom display settings.

For example to add the body a second time with the field formatter `text_summary_or_trimmed` and a custom trim length of `80`:

```
function mymodule_node_view(&$build, $entity, $display, $view_mode) {
  if (isset($build['body']['#items'])) {
    $build['body_teaser'] = $build['body']['#items']->view([
      'type' => 'text_summary_or_trimmed',
      'settings' => [
        'trim_length' => 80,
      ],
    ]);
  }
}
```

You can clone the current settings this way:

```
$build['body']['#items']->getSettings();
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to do this but it wasn't working, it was just returning an array that matched what I was passing into ->view, like this ['type' => 'google_maps_directions'], but I wasn't passing in settings, so maybe that's what I was missing.  Let me try again.

Comment: that was it, I needed to clone the settings.