# Show field twice in node page

Tags: theming, 8, entities

I created a custom bundle (content type) and I've created fields

One of those field is a file type field, is a video file, stored in the private storage. I installed the [videojs module](https://www.drupal.org/project/videojs) to allow to watch the video.

I need to show this field twice in the node page. One in the generic file formatter that allows the user to download the file, and I also need to play the video. I decided to set up as generic file formatter and customize the twig template to show again with the video player.

I achieve to show twice with the settings formatter (generic file) with this code in the node--mybundle--full.html.twig template

```
{{ content.field_sd_video }}
```

I thought it would be something easy like field+formatter:

```
{{ content.field_sd_video|videojs_formatter }}
```

But I can't find a simple way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution, I put this code in preprocess node function. It has to be easy, but not easy to know how ;)

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

     $variables['video_caption'] = $variables['node']->get('field_video')
         ->view(array(
            'label' => 'hidden',
            'type' => 'videojs_player_list'
        ));
}
```

and I only has to add this line in twig file:

```
{{ video_caption }}
```

in my case node--mybundle--full.html.twig template

Thanks @4k4 your answer was usefull

For those arrive here looking for something similar
I was inspired by [Twig Recipes](http://2016.drupalcorn.org/sites/default/files/slides/Twig%20Recipies%20-%20DrupalCorn%202016.pdf) on page 41
It was usefull for me [Twig debugging](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates). Playing with kint and node variable and the classes used to wrap the information. Then I found that the field comes with [FileFieldItemList](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21src%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldType%21FileFieldItemList.php/class/FileFieldItemList/8.2.x) and then I found the view method that uses [EntityViewBuilderInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityViewBuilderInterface.php/function/EntityViewBuilderInterface%3A%3AviewField/8.2.x)

Comment: That's a very helpful for others, providing the final solution. Btw. this is similar to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/218144/how-to-display-a-field-twice-in-a-view-mode, only that you get the field object `FileItemList` from the node and in the linked question it is coming from the source field.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in UI, UI and code mixed, code only and in html:

**Display Suite**

Install the module [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) and configure this in UI.

**Extra Field**

Use the hook [hook_entity_extra_field()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_extra_field_info/8.2.x) to get an extra field in *Manage Display*. You need [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view/8.2.x) to copy the data (in this case the file) into the new field.

**Clone field in code**

See
[How to display a field twice in a view mode?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/218144/how-to-display-a-field-twice-in-a-view-mode)

The last has the least overhead, but is not customizable and you have to define the field settings yourself. If you configure the second field temporarily in UI and export the view mode to yaml this helps to find the settings you need in code.

**Place link html in template**

Or if you want a quick solution in the template and you only need a simple formatted file link you can get the file url from the node and put it in html markup:

```
<a href="{{ file_url(node.field_video.entity.uri.value) }}">Example Video</a>
```

Comment: Or you could preprocess node too, and create a new variable that themes the value of the filefield into a link, and output that in the twig template

Comment: Yes, @Kevin. I tried that. I'm trying to get the field value and change the formatter. But I'm not sure, how can I access to the field value. In the preprocess_node I've the $variables['node'] and I know exist the [videojs theme]8http://cgit.drupalcode.org/videojs/tree/README.md#n105) function.

Comment: @4k4 I would like to not have to implement a module, I believe that the 2nd and 3rd solution needs a custom module, isn't it ? I thought I could achieve this in my own bootstrap subtheme that I already have.

Comment: @ferriol, see my 4th example