# Display Entity Reference field twice, with different display modes

Tags: theming, 8, entities

I have a content type (Type A) that has an Entity Reference field to another content type (Type B).

Type B has 3 fields and 2 display modes. Display A shows two of the fields, Display B shows the other field.

In the display settings for Type A, the display mode for the Type B entity is set to Display 1.

On the template for Type A, I can use `{{ content.field_type_b }}` and the two fields are shown.

Now, I want to be able to output the field again, but as Display 2, in a different part of the template.

In a pseudo twig code way, I'd imagine something like `{{ content.field_type_b|display_mode('display_2') }}`

I have heard suggestions for Display Suite, but I tried this and it seems whilst you can clone a field, there is no option to render it as an entity with a display mode.

I also found Twig Tweak, which I *think* might work, however, the documentation is beyond terrible and I cannot see how I'd actually use it (the cheat sheet lacks all manner of help).

If this is not possible in Twig, could this be achieved in a hook? Bearing in mind, the field I want to render in Display 2, is a nicely rendered map, so I don't want to simply get the field value, it has to be using the display mode.

Comment: There a several approaches to this, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/225381/show-field-twice-in-node-page, but since then [EVA](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva) was released and now I would attach an EVA view display to the node for an UI only solution.

Comment: How would I use EVA (in D8) to output the field twice with different display modes? there is no D8 documentation for that module.

Answer (score 0):

How to display a reference field twice with the help of EVA:

1. Install [EVA](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva).
2. Add a new View.
3. Add a display "EVA".
4. Add the Entity Reference field to FIELDS and configure the Formatter to "Rendered entity" and set the view mode `Display 2`.
5. The EVA display includes the section ENTITY CONTENT SETTINGS, choose the entity type `Content` and bundle `Type A`.
6. In the ADVANCED section add a contextual filter for `Content: ID`.
7. Save the View.
8. Now the new field is visible in the field UI of the content type `Type A` and you can drag'n'drop it to the final position.

Comment: What would the twig variable be? I am defining my template using `{{ content.field_name }}` to put fields where I want. What is the machine name for the new EVA view?

Comment: Try `{{ dump(content|keys) }}`, should be something like this `{{ content.VIEW_NAME_entity_view_1 }}`