# Render taxonomy type custom fields individually

Tags: 8, nodes, taxonomy-terms

I'm kind of a twig newbie so I'm hoping that someone can point me in the right direction.

I've added a custom field **field_url** to a taxonomy type called **field_type_poi**. How would you render that taxonomy type's individual field in **node.html.twig**? 
I know that I can use **{{ content.field_type_poi }}** to render the entire contents of the taxonomy type, but I'm looking for a way to render one field specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{ content.field_type_poi }}` doesn't necessarily render the entire content of the taxonomy term. You can select the field in the tab *Manage Display* where you've added the field `field_url` to the vocabulary.

If you need multiple field selections, here only this field, but in all other places the default selection, then add a custom view mode in *Custom Display Settings* at the bottom of the page.

Finally go to the content type and configure the  field `field_type_poi` in the tab *Manage Display* to be rendered in the view mode you've configured above.

---

**Edit:**

If you want to use different fields from the taxonomy in different locations you would need to clone the field, see [Show field twice in node page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/225381/show-field-twice-in-node-page), or install the module [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) and render single fields in Twig:

```
{% set tid = node.field_type_poi.target_id %}
{% if tid %}
  {{ drupal_field('field_url', 'taxonomy_term', tid) }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I had thought about doing it that way, but I was hoping there was a way to render each field individually where needed. The reason being, we potentially wanted to use different fields from the taxonomy in different locations, without having to create a new view-mode and render it for each scenario.

Thank you for answering my question!