# Twig D8 Field Format

Tags: theming, 8

Is it possible via Twig to output a field's value, that uses the fields formatter. I would like to display a file field two different ways in the same twig file. The first will be a link to the file with a label to the left. The second will be the SOLR Extract text from the file, with a label on the left.

Here are the formatters I am talking about.
[image: Drupal 8 entity display management]
[image]

As shown in the second image, there are multiple options for how to display the field. Is there a way in Twig to do something like the following.

```
{{ content.field_name.FORMATTER_NAME_HERE }} or
{{ content.field_name[0].value | FORMATTER_NAME_HERE }}
```

I would like to use the `URL to file` and `Text extracted from attachment` formatters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no out of the box way to display a field in twig with two different formatters.  But it can be done with a hook in a custom module.

You can repurpose a field in hook_entity_view or [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/218166/45409)().

Here's an example:

```
function mymodule_entity_view(array &$build, EntityInterface $entity, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {

  if ($entity->getEntityTypeId() == 'node' && $entity->bundle() == 'article' && $view_mode == 'teaser') {   
    $settings = [
      'type' => 'pdf_special_formatter',
      'settings' => $build['field_pdf']['#items']->getSettings(),
    ];
    $build['pdf_alternate_display'] = $build['field_pdf']['#items']->view($settings);

  }  
}
```

Note that the settings may need to be altered before sending to another field formatter.  You'll have to look at that field formatter for the required settings.

Comment: While this looks like the way to go... I can't get the field formatter `Text extracted from attachment` to show any content. However, when changing my view from `Rendered content` to `Fields` I can use `Search: Excerpt` and that will show it. Due to this I am going to look into leveraging views with `Fields` instead. I will post back progress.

Answer (score 2):

Technically it is possible. Field items have a public `view` method that accepts either view mode or field formatter. Unfortunately that method is not allowed by default Twig sandbox policy in Drupal. You need to override it in your settings.php file as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45323981/272927).

```
{{ node.field_image.view({type: 'image', settings: {image_style: 'large'}}) }}
```

An alternative approach could be using [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) module which provides a wrapper around this method.

```
{{ node.field_image|view({type: 'image', settings: {image_style: 'large'}}) }}
```