# Different Templates for Same Field

Tags: 8, theming, paragraphs

I want to have two different templates for the same field on a node template.

For example:

```
<div class="navigation>{{ content.field_section }}</div>

    // uses paragraph--section.html.twig 
    // Only want to print the titles from paragraph sections

<section>{{ content.field_section }}</section> 
    // uses paragraph--section2.html.twig
    // Want to print the body and titles from paragraph sections
```

How can I do this? Is there a way to flag one instance or force a specific template?

Comment: Hm, to me it's unclear what you are asking. What conditions should be met to decide wether to take one or the other template? I wonder if you ain't better off with some [`include`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/include.html).

Comment: Why not encapsulate this in the Paragraph bundle itself? They certainly have robust twig suggestions.

Comment: I think your best chance is to clone the field in a node view hook and set a different view mode in the field display settings. This should get you different theme name suggestions and separate caching of both rendered versions of the paragraph. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/218144/how-to-display-a-field-twice-in-a-view-mode

Comment: Maybe you can achieve what you're after with some clever code in "Rewrite output" options for that field, you can use twig there.

Answer (score -1):

You can override existing twig file in preprocess hook. You may check the link https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/working-with-twig-templates.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of two different templates for the same field.